# Creating a Separate Column for Prior Week Values (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would I go about having a separate column that shows the prior week's value? For example, if `Product A`'s value for `01/03/2021` was `100`, I would like `01/10/2021` to show its date value as well as the `01/03/2021` value in a separate column.

Desired table below (for simplicity sake I added random numbers for the prior week values for `01/03` and `01/04`):

| Date | Product | Value | Prior Week Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/03/2021 | Product A | 100 | 50 |
| 01/04/2021 | Product A | 200 | 55 |
| 01/10/2021 | Product A | 600 | 100 |
| 01/11/2021 | Product A | 700 | 200 |
| 01/03/2021 | Product B | 250 | 40 |
| 01/04/2021 | Product B | 550 | 45 |
| 01/10/2021 | Product B | 460 | 250 |
| 01/11/2021 | Product B | 100 | 550 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want exactly 7 days before, you can use window functions with a range specification:

```
select t.*,
       max(value) over (partition by product
                        order by date
                        range between '7 day' preceding and '7 day' preceding
                       ) as value_prev_week
from t;
```